# Can't install Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I'm trying to install Eclipse Oxygen 64bits in my computer and an error appears when I start the installation. The error is the following:

Internal error:
TLS SSL Context not available

And after clicking in the okay butten, the installation close.
The details of the error are this:

```
org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLInitializationException: TLS SSLContext not available
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLContexts.createDefault(SSLContexts.java:61)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLContexts.createSystemDefault(SSLContexts.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransferFactory.newInstance(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransferFactory.java:27)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.internal.provider.filetransfer.Activator.getFileTransfer(Activator.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.MultiProtocolRetrieveAdapter.sendRetrieveRequest(MultiProtocolRetrieveAdapter.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.util.ECFURIHandlerImpl$InputStreamConnectionHandler.sendConnectionRequest(ECFURIHandlerImpl.java:1641)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.util.ECFURIHandlerImpl$ConnectionHandler.process(ECFURIHandlerImpl.java:1392)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.util.ECFURIHandlerImpl.createInputStream(ECFURIHandlerImpl.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ExtensibleURIConverterImpl.createInputStream(ExtensibleURIConverterImpl.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceImpl.load(ResourceImpl.java:1269)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.util.SetupCoreUtil.handleArchiveRedirection(SetupCoreUtil.java:549)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.util.SetupCoreUtil.configureResourceSet(SetupCoreUtil.java:348)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.util.SetupCoreUtil.configureResourceSet(SetupCoreUtil.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.util.SetupCoreUtil.createResourceSet(SetupCoreUtil.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.wizards.SetupWizard.<init>(SetupWizard.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.wizards.SetupWizard.<init>(SetupWizard.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.Installer.<init>(Installer.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.InstallerApplication.run(InstallerApplication.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.InstallerApplication.start(InstallerApplication.java:408)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: TLS SSLContext not available
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLContexts.createDefault(SSLContexts.java:57)
    ... 30 more
```

Hope you can help me, thank you.

Comment: On what O.S.? With what version of Java?

Comment: Windows 10 64bits and Java 1.8.0_144 also 64 bits

Comment: What is prompt for `java -version` on the command line? Could you try to [specify your Java 8 JRE in the _ini_ file of the Eclipse Installer](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value:_Windows_Example)?

Comment: java version "1.8.0_144"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode) This is what java -version show. I don't have the config.ini cause I can't install Eclipse, the error appears when I open the installer